# Change the width of the facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I need to change the width of the like button in my website. I have changed the width property in the code but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429092/change-the-width-of-a-like-button

Answer (score 1):

You can visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ to create the button of your desired width.

Comment: Yes I used that link.The total width is getting changed and not the button width.why is it so ?

Comment: That's because you change the width of the iframe it's in, not the button itself, you might find a solution using the developer tools in your preferred browser, but it's most likely you will have to make a new button and put a link to a yql call to the facebook api

Comment: @JoeriMinnekeer There's no Facebook API for like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to change the width of the button itself, only the container it is in.  You are not allowed to overlay any other click-jacking image over the top of the like button either.